# What does backing store option do while creating a VM in Virtual manager?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, storage, kali-linux-tools

I am creating a virtual machine using virtual manager in linux. While adding a new instance it provides us an option to add storage. When we create a new volume storage. It provides us an option of backing store. This backing stores takes a path of file as an input. Can anybody explain me in detail what does this backing store mean and what does it do?